# How to delete a certain column (s) from big csv file in Windows?

Tags: csv, windows-console

The files sizes might be over 1GB. 
I can write a script, but I wonder if there is a simple way, for example using Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: Load it in Excel, delete the column, re-save it.

Comment: What's wrong with your script solution? Reading a line at a time and then writing a new file removing a column is a good solution which will not use much memory (although you need storage space for filesize * 2, which shouldn't be an problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following solution:

1. Install FileUtils package from GnuWin32 project. 

2. run command in command promt:

```
cut -f<idxColumn> --complement -d,  <inputFile>  >  <outputFile>
```

For example:

cut -f3 --complement -d,  d:/in.csv  >  d:/out.csv